# Java Window in another Window

Tags: java, swing, window, awt, mdi

Multi-window applications often have a main-window, and all other windows are kind of 'parented' to it. Minimizing such a *sub-window* will hide its content and show the title-bar at the bottom-left of the screen. Also, these windows do not have their own Icon in the Task-bar, only the main-window does.

1. How can I make a window being attached this way to another window?
2. If that is possible, is it also possible without a referenfe to the actual main window?

@2: I'm embedding Java into such an application and I would like to be able to use awt or swing additionally to the native dialogs, which have this behavior by default.

Answer (score 5):

See [How to Use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

- have look at `JInternalFrames` for `MDI` application
- read [Oracle tutorial, try code example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)